# Find all polynomials $p: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ with $p(a)p(b) \in p(\mathbb{Z})$ for $a,b\in\mathbb Z$.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

> Find all polynomials $p: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that for any $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, there is $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $p(c) = p(a)p(b)$.

I suspect $p(x) = (x - k)^n$ but I'm having trouble proving it...

Comment: Should $p$ have integer coefficients? (There are polynomials without integer coefficients that map $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$.) Not that this necessarily matters.

Comment: I think $p(x)=4x+1$ works.

Comment: Indeed, every $p(x)=kx+1$, $k$ integer, works.

Comment: And also $p(x)=(kx+1)^n$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson In general, if $p(x)$ works then so does $p(x)^n$.

Comment: And there is a very nice and **wrong** argument to "show" that if two polynomials work then so does their product...

Comment: Is there any known result like "if all values of a degree $n$ polynomial $p$ are $n$-th power of integers, then..."?

Comment: In general, if $p(x)$ is a solution, then $p(x)^n$, $p(x-k)$ and $p(d)p(x)$ are all solutions. Our base cases are thus all linear so far, $p(x)=mx+1$ an $p(x)=x$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson, I know that the result is true for squares, i.e., if a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ takes only square values, then it is a square. Not sure about the general case, though.

Comment: @u1571372 Yes, I also remembered the result for squares. That proof seems to be possible to be modified to higher degrees, which would solve this problem. But that's only speculation...

Comment: @CaveJohnson, in fact, after googling a bit, I discovered that the result is true for general $n$. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224881/polynomials-which-always-assume-perfect-power-values.

Comment: @u1571372 Thanks a lot! That's an even stronger result than I thought...I think it leads to a solution.

Comment: A linear example not covered by my above comment is $15x+6$. In general, $mx+n$ is a solution if and only if $n^2\equiv n\pmod m$.

Comment: I dont see how the only if could be proved...

Comment: Is that a question for me? @WouterRienks It's pretty direct. $(ma+n)(mb+n)\equiv n^2\pmod m$, while $mc+n\equiv n\pmod m$, so for $c$ to exist, $n^2\equiv n\pmod {m}$.

Comment: $(mx-1)^2$ is a solution, when $mx-1$ is not. For example, when $m=3$, $(3a-1)^2(3b-1)^2=(9ab-3(a+b)+1)^2=(3(a+b-3ab)-1)^2$.

Answer (score 10):

**Edited.** Now we present a complete solution to the original problem.
**Edited again.** Thanks for [@lhf](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/589/lhf), who pointed out a flaw in the argument. The original answer missed some solutions by claiming that $a\mid b(b-1)\implies a\mid b$ or $a\mid (b-1)$, which is incorrect. Fortunately, that wasn't a serious problem, since we may just write the solutions with the restriction $a\mid b(b-1)$ instead of $a\mid b$ or $a\mid(b-1)$.

> **Answer.** All possible $p\in\mathbb Q[x]$, with $p(\mathbb Z)\subseteq\mathbb Z$ and satisfying the given condition, can be expressed in one of the following form, with $a,b,n,k$ integers, $a\not=0,n>0$:
>   $$p(x)\equiv 0 \text{  or  } p(x)\equiv 1$$
>   $$p(x)=(ax+b)^n,\quad \text{with }a\mid b(b-1)$$
>   $$p(x)=(ax+b)^{2n},\quad \text{with }a\mid b(b+1)$$

---

Let $n=\deg p$. We first prove that $p(x)$ must be of the form $(ax+b)^n$.

> **Claim.** $p(k)$ is a perfect $n$-th power for any $k\in\mathbb Z$.
>
> **Proof.** Suppose $p(k)\not=0$. For each $a$ there exists some $c(a)$ such that $p(k)=p(c(a))/(p(a)$. We may observe that for sufficiently large $a$, we have $|c(a)|\ge (1-\epsilon)|a|$ since $|p(k)|\ge 1$, hence $c(a)\to\infty$ as $a\to\infty$, and $(c(a)/a)^n\to p(c(a))/p(a)=p(k)$. Now suppose $\lambda=\sqrt[n]{p(k)}\not=0$ is irrational. First we assume $n$ is odd, so that we have $c/a\to\lambda$. We present some estimation
>   $$\left|\left(\frac c a\right)^n-\frac{p(c)}{p(a)}\right|=\left|\left(\frac c a\right)^{n-1}\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\left(\frac c a-1\right)\frac 1 a\right|+\mathcal O(a^{-2})$$
>   ($a_n,a_{n-1}$ is the coefficient of $x^n,x^{n-1}$ in $p(x)$, respectively) Denote by $\mu$ the ratio $a_{n-1}/a_n$, we have
>   $$a\left|\left(\frac c a\right)^n-\frac{p(c)}{p(a)}\right|\to|\lambda|^{n-1}|\mu||\lambda-1|$$
>   Hence
>   $$a\left|\left(\frac c a\right)^n-\lambda^n\right|=a|\lambda|^n\left|1-\left(1-\frac{\lambda-c/a}\lambda\right)^n\right|\to|\lambda|^{n-1}|\mu||\lambda-1|$$
>   Now note that
>    $$\left|1-\left(1-\frac{\lambda-c/a}\lambda\right)^n\right|= \frac{n|\lambda-c/a|}{\lambda}+\mathcal O((\lambda-c/a)^2)$$
>   We conclude that
>   $$|a\lambda-c|=|\mu||\lambda-1|/n+\mathcal O(a^{-1})$$
>   For the case where $n$ is even, the reasoning is not quite different: the negative part of $c/a$ tends to $-\lambda$ and the positive part tends to $\lambda$. The estimations remain almost the same except for some sign change. In other words, we have
>   $$|a^-\lambda+c(a^-)|\to|\mu||\lambda+1|/n$$
>   $$|a^+\lambda-c(a^+)|\to|\mu||\lambda-1|/n$$
>   Here $\{a^+\}$ denotes the subset of $\mathbb Z$ where $c/a\ge0$, and the similar for $\{a^-\}$. The two sets form a partition of $\mathbb Z$. Obviously those limit properties are impossible for irrational $\lambda$ (by considering the fractional part of $a\lambda$), whereby we proved the rationality  of $\lambda$. Since $p(k)\in\mathbb Z$, we may assert that $\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Now, as @u1571372 kindly pointed out in the comment, [known results](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224881/polynomials-which-always-assume-perfect-power-values) have shown that $p$ must be of the form $(ax+b)^n$(note that int the MO post it's assumed that $p(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$, to which we may reduce the original problem by multiplying a factor $d^n$). In fact this can be done by more elementary method in our situation, where more restrictions are put on $p$, instead of the somehow overkill methods mentioned in the MO post. The main point is as following: since $|a^+\lambda-c(a^+)|$ is a integer sequence tending to a limit, for sufficiently large $a^+$ the expression is a constant. So for some $l$ the equality $p(\lambda x+l)=\lambda^n p(x)$ holds for infinitely many $x$. But it's a polynomial equation in $x$, so in fact it's an identity. Now it's not difficult to arrive at the conclusion by comparing coefficients(or more smartly, comparing derivatives of all orders).

---

At last we conclude the solution by considering all polynomials of the form $(ax+b)^n$. It's plain that $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ since $p(\mathbb Z)\subseteq\mathbb Z$. Note that $\sqrt[n]{p(u)p(v)}=a^2 uv+ab(u+v)+b^2$. When $n$ is odd, $(aw+b)^n=p(u)p(v)$ implies $aw+b=a^2 uv+ab(u+v)+b^2$, so the existence of $w$ is reduced to $b^2\equiv b\pmod{|a|}$, which is equivalent to $a\mid b(b-1)$. When $n$ is even, more possibility is allowed: we may have $aw+b=-(a^2 uv+ab(u+v)+b^2)$. It turns out that it's equivalent to $a\mid b(b-1)$ or $a\mid b(b+1)$ in this case. Now we're done.

Comment: "$b^2\equiv b\bmod{|a|}$, which is equivalent to $a\mid b$ or $a\mid (b-1)$" — this assumes that $a$ is prime. It fails for $a=6$ and $b=3$.

Comment: @lhf Thanks for pointing out the flaw. I find myself repeating this same mistake over and over again when dealing with problems in number theory...So maybe I should just write the solution as "$p(x)=(ax+b)^n$ ,where a\mid b(b-1)$", etc?